# Finding Date of Birth given age in months

Tags: c#, date-arithmetic

I'm really stuck with calculating date of birth given a persons age in months. Currently, I'm using C# to do that. However, failed to understand the logic. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the logic that you did not understand? And what is the area where you have a problem?

Comment: Like if I'm provided a persons age in years. I can simply subtract it from the current year and assign the current date and month as part of the date of birth - that's what my project team accepted! But, the same logic could not be applied for age in terms of Month. Eg. someones' age is 18 months.

Comment: So what prevents you from subtracting months from a given DateTime object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DateTime has perfect method to substract (actually add negative value) months from current date. For example:

```
int ageInMonths = 18;
DateTime dt = DateTime.Today;
DateTime DateOfBirth = dt.AddMonths(-ageInMonths);
```